# Correct usage of "verb+ing" used as an adjective

Tags: grammaticality

Sentence -

1. It's literally annoying to tell someone to do all the work.

I have a doubt regarding the implication of this above mentioned sentence , who's being annoyed here the person who's being told to do all the work , or the person who's telling the other one to do all the work .

From what I know , it should mean that it's annoying to be told to do all the work . But it's said in a different way .. and it doesn't matter how you say it implication remains the same

Comment: Written like this, the sentence does indeed convey that it is annoying for the one who's giving the order. For it to mean what you're really intending it to mean, you could try this version: _It is literally annoying to be told (or when someone tells you) to do all the work._

Comment: @user405662 What about this sentence - It's really discouraging to tell someone to do all the work .    Does this sentence imply that it's discouraging for the person who's telling someone to do all the work

Comment: You have a doubt, or you have a question?

Comment: @Xanne I have a doubt and I want it to be clarified

Comment: The use of "literally" seems odd. Where did you find this sentence?

Comment: user405662 is right: it's annoying for the person telling. If you want to say it's annoying for the person who is told, say "it's annoying to be told." I would leave out "It's literally". It literally doesn't add anything.